# Split a Map<String,String> into List<Map<String,String>> with equal size

Tags: hashmap

I've a map Map having 5 entries and want to convert it into List> with where each Map in list is having 2 entries and last entry with remaining data e.g. 1 (5- 2*2 =1).

I know that I can get it first entry by using below code-

```
  Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<>();
         a.put("1","One");
         a.put("4","Two");
         a.put("5","Five");
         a.put("2","Two");
         a.put("3","Three");

a.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(o->o.getKey())).limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Is there any way to get it in simple fashion?

Answer (score 0):

I got below piece of code which is working perfectly fine as per mentioned requirement -

```
public static <K, V> Collector<Map.Entry<K, V>, ?, List<Map<K, V>>> splitMap(int limit) {
    return Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
            (l, e) -> {
              if (l.isEmpty() || l.get(l.size() - 1).size() == limit) {
                l.add(new HashMap<>());
              }
              l.get(l.size() - 1).put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            },
            (l1, l2) -> {
              if (l1.isEmpty()) {
                return l2;
              }
              if (l2.isEmpty()) {
                return l1;
              }
              if (l1.get(l1.size() - 1).size() < limit) {
                Map<K, V> map = l1.get(l1.size() - 1);
                ListIterator<Map<K, V>> mapsIte = l2.listIterator(l2.size());
                while (mapsIte.hasPrevious() && map.size() < limit) {
                  Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> ite = mapsIte.previous().entrySet().iterator();
                  while (ite.hasNext() && map.size() < limit) {
                    Map.Entry<K, V> entry = ite.next();
                    map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    ite.remove();
                  }
                  if (!ite.hasNext()) {
                    mapsIte.remove();
                  }
                }
              }
              l1.addAll(l2);
              return l1;
            }
    );
  }


List<Map<String,String>> listofMaps = a.entrySet().stream().collect(splitMap(2));
System.out.println(listofMaps);
```

Output ->
[{1=One, 2=Two}, {3=Three, 4=Two}, {5=Five}]